# How to correctly load and execute JavaScript within Webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node-modules, webpacker

I have a Ruby on Rails 6 app with Webpacker. I am implementing an existing bootstrap theme that was not developed for Webpacker.

The theme uses node_modules for various JavaScript features. The theme also has lots of little JavaScript files that specify options and trigger the execution of various node_modules. I have one JavaScript file from the theme for the Typed.js feature that types out sentences in an animation. That file contains an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) function.

/app/javascript/src/typed.js

```js
(function() {

  //
  // Variables
  //

  var toggle = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="typed"]');

  //
  // Functions
  //

  function init(el) {
    var elementOptions = el.dataset.options;
        elementOptions = elementOptions ? JSON.parse(elementOptions) : {};
    var defaultOptions = {
      typeSpeed: 40,
      backSpeed: 40,
      backDelay: 1000,
      loop: true
    }
    var options = Object.assign(defaultOptions, elementOptions);

    // Init
    new Typed(el, options);
  }

  //
  // Events
  //

  if (typeof Typed !== 'undefined' && toggle) {
    [].forEach.call(toggle, function(el) {
      init(el);
    });
  }
})();
```

In my Ruby on Rails application.js file, I then load the node_module class like so. Take note that the 'typed.js' file here is not my src/typed.js file -- two separate things:

#### File */app/javascript/packs/application.js*

```
import Typed from 'typed.js';

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    var inputTZ = document.getElementById("timezone");
    if(inputTZ) {
        inputTZ.value = jstz.determine().name();
    }
});
```

Now I need to load and execute the code from the *src/typed.js* file within the EventListener block.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => { ... });
```

How do I correctly export the code from the src/typed.js file, import it to the application.js file and then execute it within the EventListener block? Do I even need an IIFE inside the *src/typed.js* file?

What I've tried: I copied all the code from the *src/typed.js* file and pasted that inside the EventListener block and it runs fine. But, I want to keep the *src/typed.js* file in place as I have a lot more of these types of files for other node_module features.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I am getting it working like this, but please let me know if there are better ways to do this.

I change the *src/typed.js* file to the below, getting rid of the IIFE and, importantly, I import the core class from within this file:

```
import Typed from 'typed.js';

export default function() {
  // ... same code as in the original file ...
}
```

Then, in the *application.js* file, I do:

```
import typed from '../src/typed.js';

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {

    typed();

});
```

Comment: That’s pretty much how I’d do it.

Comment: Sorry, I've got to ask: how do you call the Typed function in the html.erb?